# Mockito mocked object suddenly throws NPE

Tags: java, groovy, mockito

I have a mock:

```
 static MyGroovyBasedHttpClient createClient(){
    MyGroovyBasedHttpClient client = mock(MyGroovyBasedHttpClient.class);
    Answer<SimpleResponse> methodAnswer = createGenericAnswer();

    when(client.myMethod(anyString(), anyInt(),anyString())).thenAnswer(methodAnswer);
    return client;
}
```

And I have method invocation

```
def response = client.myMethod(stringParam1, intParam2, stringParam3)
```

And I get NPE on **client.myMethod** invocation
If i do

```
println client // mock for MyGroovyBasedHttpClient with hashcode
```

so 100% client is initialized and not NULL
I even hace smoke assertions that mocked components are not null.
Also I have smoke on static **MyGroovyBasedHttpClient createClient()**
Smoke checks that mocked client does return my custom Answer

How can I debug such problem?

UPD:
Look like this is my problem: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=303

Comment: What is `someId, someStuff, otherStuff`

Comment: Hi, I've edited stringParam1, intParam2, stringParam3. You suppose that method signature is wrong?

Comment: What does createGenericAnswer look like? Does your NPE happen during mock set-up, or within the Answer, or in code that uses myMethod's return value?

Comment: npe happens on client.myMethod(stringParam1, intParam2, stringParam3). I did debug it. I don't understand where it happens. There is no Answer in stacktrace. Look like mockito tries find a method and fails to find it. And it returns null and then failes with NPE. "client" object itself is not null. I'm confused.

Comment: @Sergey As mentioned in the answer below there are issues with mockito and groovy. I don't see the point of using Mockito with Groovy anyway. Groovy has quite a lot of goodnes for mocking built in the language itself. If you need anything more go for Spock Framework. The simplest Groovy 'mock' which should work in your can be constructed with _Groovy Coercion_ and would look like: `{ methodAnswer } as MyGroovyBasedHttpClient`. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Mocks | https://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try suggested frameworks. The only reason I use groovy and java-mockito because groovy gives me significant coding speed-up and  I know a little mockito. Definitely, my chosen java-zoo is ugly. Thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with mockito and groovy, you need additional dependency or you can mock only interfaces.

For more info visit : 
https://github.com/cyrusinnovation/mockito-groovy-support

Issue 303 about mockito problem with groovy classes :
https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=303